# How can I solve $2^{x}+1=y^{2}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I found an **exponential equation** with two variables $x$ and $y$, and I can't find the solutions. I want to solve it for $x$ and $y$. I tried using logarithms but I couldn't solve it. This is the equation: 
$$2^{x}+1=y^{2}\qquad\text{with }\big(x,y\big)\in\mathbb{N}.$$

Comment: How are $x,\,y$ restricted? For example, are they non-negative integers? If so, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture).

Comment: Yes, $\big(x,y\big)\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: $x$ being odd implies $y$ having a divisor of $3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $2^x=y^2−1=(y+1)(y−1) \Rightarrow y+1 = 2^a$ and $y-1 = 2^b$, where $x=a+b$. Then, we have $a \geq b$, and $2^a-2^b= (y+1) - (y-1) = 2$, which gives us $2^b(2^{a-b}-1)=2$. So, we have the following cases:

(I) $\left\{\begin{array}[rcl]  
22^b& = & 1 \\
2^{a-b}-1 & = & 2
\end{array} \right. $ $\quad$ (II) $\left\{\begin{array}[rcl]  
22^b& = & 2 \\
2^{a-b}-1 & = & 1
\end{array} \right. $

Note that (I) is not possible. From (II), $b=1$ and $a=2$, and so $y=3$ and $x=3$.

Comment: Wait if $b=1$ then $2^{a-1}=0$ and that's imposible, right?

Comment: Actually, if $b=1$, then $2^{a-1}=2$ and so $a=2$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was wrong, sorry

Answer (score 5):

Hint. If $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$2^x=y^2-1=(y+1)(y-1)$$
then $(y+1)$ and $(y−1)$ are both powers of $2$ and their difference is $2$. What may we conclude?

Comment: Yes, I tried that.

Comment: So $(y+1)$ and $(y-1)$ are both powers of $2$. What may we conclude?

Comment: they aren't powers of $2$ $\forall y$

Comment: then y will be odd, right?

Comment: The powers of $2$ are $1,2,4,8,16,\dots$, There is just one couple of powers with difference $2$: $y+1=4$ and $y-1=2$.

Comment: umm... got it, but what if $y+1=8$ then $y-1=6$, why did you choose 4 and 2

Comment: Is $6$ a power of $2$?

Comment: Ah... you took a couple of two powers of two, ok

Comment: The equation $2^x=(y+1)(y-1)$ implies that
 $(y+1)$ and $(y−1)$ are both divisors of $2^x$.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to proof it

Comment: @Anonymous Well done!

Answer (score 3):

So $y$ is odd: $y=2z+1$ so $$2^x= 4z(z+1)$$

Since $z$ and $z+1$ are consecutive one must be odd and since only odd factor on left is $1$ we have two possibilities:

- $z=1$ then $2^x=8$ so $x=3$ and $y=3$.
- $z+1=1$ then $z=0$ but this can not be.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest solution is $x=y=3$. Any larger solution contradicts [Mihailescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), which states $8,\,9$ are the only consecutive integers of the form $n^k$ with $n,\,k\in\Bbb N,\,k\ge2$. But as @RobertZ notes, that's overkill: $y\pm1$ need to be powers of two, making them $2,\,4$, giving the above solution.

Comment: But I want a hint to proof that $x=y=3$

Comment: @Anonymous The hint is when do $2$ powers of $2$ differ by $2$?

Answer (score 0):

$$2^{x}+1=y^{2} \implies y=\pm \sqrt {2^x+1}$$

You are interested only in natural numbers solutin so we get

$$y= \sqrt {2^x+1}$$

For those natural numbers $x$ where $2^x+1$ is a perfect square.

$x=y=3$ is the only solution.

Note that you want to have  $2^x = (y-1)(y+1)$ so both $y-1$ and $y+1$ must be powers of $2$ which is possible only if  $y=3$